# Unable to insert Arabic alphabets in DB

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, arabic-support

I am trying to run sql file with below insert query, where this query has to insert arabic alphabets

```
 INSERT INTO language
                  (locale_id, language_id,
                   VALUE
                  )
           VALUES (4011951073333968003, 9161117031233296391,
                   'ابةتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوي'
                  );
```

But the result of this query is,

```
INSERT INTO language
            (locale_id, language_id,
             VALUE
            )
         VALUES (4011951073333968003, 9161117031233296391,
              'ÙŠÙˆÙ‡Ù†Ù…Ù„ÙƒÙ‚ÙØºØ¹Ø¸Ø·Ø¶ØµØ´Ø³Ø²Ø±Ø°Ø¯Ø®Ø­Ø¬Ø«ØªØ¨Ø£'
            );
```

I am facing this issue, even though, I have set charset to UTF-8.

**Second problem** :
If I try to specify a number following Arabic alphabets, it is misplaced and get inserted before the declaration of Arabic alphabets, like,

```
       INSERT INTO language
                  (locale_id, language_id,
                   VALUE, priority
                  )
           VALUES (4011951073333968003, 9161117031233296391,
                   1,'ابةتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوي'
                  );
```

Here, Corresponding **priority** value is 1 but I am unable to declare it after Arabic script, every time, it moves at the beginning, if I declare it after the script.
Can anyone suggest me the solution to resolve this problem?

Comment: What is a character set of your database and your session? You need to check `NLS_CHARACTERSET` parameter of your database (which is responsible for storage) and `NLS_LANG` setting of your client (which is responsible for RTL and input encoding)

Comment: Show the results of these queries: `select sid,serial#,client_charset,client_driver from V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO where sid=userenv('sid');` and `select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';`

Comment: And I haven't understood your "second problem": what does mean "it moves at the beginning" - how do you notice/check it? Describe this problem using screenshots

Comment: Which tool do you use?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov  result of the   **select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';**   AL32UTF8

Comment: result of the **select sid,serial#,client_charset,client_driver from V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO where sid=userenv('sid');** `SID, SERIAL#, CLIENT_CHARSET, CLIENT_DRIVER
750 24322 Unknown jdbcthin : 19.3.0.0.0
750 24322 Unknown jdbcthin : 19.3.0.0.0
750 24322 Unknown jdbcthin : 19.3.0.0.0`

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov, It's hard to explain it, but I will try and suggest you to do below steps in Intellij tool Please create an sql file, and try to insert value like, `INSERT INTO language
                  (locale_id, language_id,
                   VALUE, priority
                  )VALUES (4011951073333968003, 9161117031233296391,
                   'arabic alphabet', 1
                  );` (NOTE : replace the arabic alphabet with actual script as given in question). The position of the value 1 changes and it is placed before the arabic script, which is not right.

Comment: Looks like you use a Java/JDBC based tool, e.g. SQL Developer. In this case forget all about `NLS_LANG`,- Java does not use `NLS_LANG` settings, see [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643)